# trying to create table from existing table (Structure only)

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

```
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
objAccess.DoCmd.rename "new_", 0, "new"
```

Here it renames the `new` to `new_` which works fine and renames successfully

```
Curmonth1  = [new]
Curmonth2  = [new_]

objAccess.DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * INTO" & Curmonth1 & "FROM" & Curmonth2 & "WHERE 1 = 2"
```

This query is working fine sometimes and throwing below error sometimes
runtime error 2501 the run command action was cancelled.
As I'm passing 2 variables into the query in VBA when working with Access DB

Tried with this query too

```
objAccess.DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE TABLE" & Curmonth1 & "AS SELECT * FROM" & Curmonth2 & "WHERE 1 = 2"
```

this doesn't works at all.

Help me out. any other queries which can work.
I feel some database refresh should be done in between those 2queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy a table structure without its contents, try this:

```
'copy table without data with new name
    strPath = CurrentProject.FullName
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", strPath, acTable, "SourceTableName", "NewTableName", True
```

Edit: As a (confusing) one-liner:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", CurrentProject.FullName, acTable, "SourceTableName", "NewTableName", True
```

Edit: Try this code in a separate sub and check if it works (replace "SourceTableName"):

```
Sub testSub()

    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", CurrentProject.FullName, acTable, "SourceTableName", "NewTableName", True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi David,                                                                                                    Thanks for the quick response                                                                    what is strpath here,is it path of Access DB ? what we need to pass in this variable

Comment: Yes, `CurrentProject.FullName` returns a string of the full name of your current database. The first version needs of course a `Dim strPath As String` added at the declarations

Comment: objAccess.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", objAccess.CurrentProject.FullName, acTable, [new_], [new], True                                                                                                            its throwing error.expression u entered is a wrong data type

Comment: where does the "**objAccess**" part come from?

Comment: tried with currentProject.FullName but throwing error saying object required..as objAccess here is object created earlier

Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

Comment: still not working same error. even though its kept in Sub